# Загрузка файлов в память смартфона

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, я только начал изучать java и android и у меня возник вопрос:
мне надо загрузить файлы (небольшого размера) из интернета в память телефона. Знаю, что есть множество способов сделать это, например, AsyncTask или DownloadManager.

**Вот пример:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://eastbancgroup.com/images/ebtLogo.gif";

    ImageView imageView;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //Получаем ссылку на DownloadManager сервис
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        //Создаем новый запрос
        Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(IMAGE_URL));
        request.setTitle("Title"); //заголовок будущей нотификации
        request.setDescription("My description"); //описание будущей нотификации
        request.setMimeType("application/my-mime"); //mine type загружаемого файла

        //Установите следующий флаг, если хотите,
        //что-бы уведомление осталось по окончании загрузки
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        //Добавляем запрос в очередь
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Подписываемся на сообщения от сервиса
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED));
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Отписываемся от сообщений сервиса
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    };

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            //Сообщение о том, что загрузка закончена
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)){
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();          
                query.setFilterById(downloadId);
                Cursor cursor = dm.query(query);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {                      
                        String uriString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                    }
                }

            //Сообщение о клике по нотификации
            } else if (DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action)){
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                //несколько параллельных загрузок могут быть объеденены в одну нотификацию,
                //по этому мы пытаемся получить список всех загрузок, связанных с 
                //выбранной нотификацией
                long[] ids = intent.getLongArrayExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_CLICK_DOWNLOAD_IDS);
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(ids);
                Cursor cursor = dm.query(query);
                int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        //здесь вы можете получить id загрузки и
                        //реализовать свое поведение
                        long downloadId = cursor.getLong(idIndex);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }   
    };
}
```

Но вот везде пример одновременной загрузки только 1 файла, а мне нужно загрузить где-то 20-30 файлов. AsyncTask для этого, я так понял, не подходит. В общем может есть какой пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask подойдет, если вы будете загружать все это в сервисе (aka Service). Почему в сервисе? Потому что при изменении конфигурации в Activity вы потеряете этот AsyncTask (если конечно не сохраните его в фрагменте например). В методе doinbackground в цикле загружайте по 1 файлу в и onProgress кидайте события загрузки файла.

Более продвинутый вариант - [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). Используя его можно настроить количество одновременных скачиваний, а для запуска можно будет передать сразу 30 заданий на скачивание и трава не расти. В частности посмотрите [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).